# How to load color gradient while background image loads due to slow internet connection?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to load color gradient while my background image loads but it is displaying even if image is loading. How can i write my CSS, so that color gradient will not be display if image is loaded?
Please look the sample code i have tried:

```
background: url("../images/contactBg.jpg"), linear-gradient(rgba(3, 34, 47, 0.8), #01010e);
```

Comment: It seems that your approach should just work on most browsers (IE9+)?

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind adding another html markup, you can wrap the div with background image inside a div with background gradient.

Comment: The image loading is PNG so after loading the image color gradient should not be visible and the way you suggested will keep gradient as it is behind the image

Comment: @AkashJain I see, I think you can't do that with CSS alone. Maybe try using jquery `.load()` to load the image then replace the class of the div when the request completes.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think (or at least know) of any way to do this only in CSS.

A workaround is to use the [JQuery load function](http://api.jquery.com/load/) (not tested):

```
$('#mydiv').load('../images/contactBg.jpg', function() {
   //image has loaded, remove the background and add the image
   $('#mydiv').css("background", "none");
   $('#mydiv').css('background-image', 'url(../images/contactBg.jpg)');
});
```

That way, set the css of `#mydiv` to `background: linear-gradient(rgba(3, 34, 47, 0.8)`, and when the image will be loaded, this will remove the gradient and replace it with the image.

Comment: @Mazino S Ukah - It does work, please see working fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/k77dsyc2/1/
FYI, specifying I did not test the code means this was a guideline to solve the issue, not the exact solution.